# Problemas con metodos de clase c#

Tags: c#, poo

estoy teniendo problemas, mas que nada por ignorancia.
Tengo la clase Numero, que solo tiene el elemento valor (que es un int) e implementa un metodo que lo compara con otro numero y dice si son iguales

```
public bool sosIgual(int objeto)
        {
            return this.Equals(objeto);
        }
```

Si yo luego en el main creo un numero, por ejemplo:

`Numero n1 = new Numero(5);`
`Numero n2 = new Numero(5);`

Y luego pruebo:

`n1.sosIgual(n2);`

Siempre me da false. Mi verdadera pregunta es, como hago para referenciarme a la variable n1 en el metodo? la palabra this hace referencia a el?

Gracias y disculpen si no me exprese bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `sosIgual()` tiene como parámetro un entero y le estás pasando un objeto de tipo Numero.

El método debería ser:

```
public bool sosIgual(Numero objeto)
  {
     return this.valor.Equals(objeto.valor);
  }
```

Si quieres que reciba un número entonces:

```
sosIgual(n2.valor);
```

Y el método:

```
 public bool sosIgual(int objeto)
  {
    return this.valor.Equals(valor);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Su pregunta es muy interesante y me gustaria mostrarle otra forma de obtener el mismo resultado:

```
public class Numero 
    {
        private int _Numero;

        public Numero(int numero)
        {
            _Numero = numero;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Numero numero &&
                   _Numero == numero._Numero;
        }

        public bool sosIgual(Numero objeto)
         {
             return this.Equals(objeto);
         }
    }
```

La verdad el metodo Equals le permite comparar 2 objectos del mismo tipo y no tiene necesidad de crear un nuevo metodo para esto. Cada clase hereda de la clase Object y esta tiene definido Equals y HashCode que pueden ser redefinidos usando polimorfismos.

El uso es :

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Numero n1 = new Numero(4);
            Numero n2 = new Numero(4);


            Console.WriteLine($"Numeros iguales con {n1.Equals(n2)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Sos iguales con {n1.sosIgual(n2)}");
        }
    }
```

Espero esto le ayude.